# A redundant for loop/switch statement seems to improve performance

Tags: c++

I was messing with an old program I created which loops through all pieces on a Peg Solitaire board trying every move available. When I noticed I added a unneeded switch statement that would call a function, with differing parameters in each case, with a for loop triggering all possible cases. All when I could have simply called the function 4 times. However in fixing that, the time to complete almost doubled, when surely it could only improve performance?

The code:

```
int compass = 0; int direc = 0; int _direc = 0; int coords;
int move(int direc, int _direc, int coords);
int attempt(std::string in) {
  if(pathCount==pieceCount && in[16] == '@') return 0;

  for(int c = 0; c < 33; c++){
      int coords = char_to_xy[c];
      if( _b[pathCount][c] == '@'){
            for (compass = 0; compass < 4; compass++) {
                switch (compass) {
                    case(0): if(coords < 58){direc = 10; _direc= 20; move(direc, _direc, coords);} break;
                    case(1): if(coords < 76){direc = 1; _direc= 2; move(direc, _direc, coords);} break;
                    case(2): if(coords > 30){direc = -10; _direc= -20; move(direc, _direc, coords);} break;
                    case(3): if(coords > 12){direc = -1; _direc= -2; move(direc, _direc, coords);} break;
                }
            }
        }
  }
  pathCount--;
  return 0;
}
```

Time: 688.279 ms

Or without the unneeded for/switch:

```
int compass = 0; int direc = 0; int _direc = 0; int coords;
int move(int direc, int _direc, int coords);
int attempt(std::string in) {
  if(pathCount==pieceCount && in[16] == '@') return 0;

  for(int c = 0; c < 33; c++){
      int coords = char_to_xy[c];
      if( _b[pathCount][c] == '@'){
            if(coords < 58){direc = 10; _direc= 20; move(direc, _direc, coords);}
            if(coords < 76){direc = 1; _direc= 2; move(direc, _direc, coords);}
            if(coords > 30){direc = -10; _direc= -20; move(direc, _direc, coords);}
            if(coords > 12){direc = -1; _direc= -2; move(direc, _direc, coords);}
        }
  }
  pathCount--;
  return 0;
}
```

Time: 1382.78 ms

Comment: What's the point in having a `switch` statement if it's the sole statement inside a `for` loop that will take every case anyway?

Comment: How do you generate?

Comment: What compiler and what optimization flags are you using?

Comment: @Blaze hence why I described it as a 'redundant mistake'.

Comment: @zteffi g++ -O3

Comment: Really the only thing you can do is look at the compiled assembly and try to work out what the difference in optimizations are. It could be something as obvious as loop unrolling.

Comment: Check the assembly code. It is possible that in the "Time: 688.279 ms" code , inner for loop + switch is simply replaced by a if/else block, and in the "Time: 1382.78 ms" code, the compiler produces a code which checks all 4 if conditions.

Comment: @nivpeled ok, well I'll try having a look at the assembly as soon as I can.

Comment: my guess is branch prediction failure, try some of the 4! = 12 arrangements of the if clauses and tell us the timings.

Comment: It could also be faster by accident, due to the change of memory layout.  Checkout  the [talk](https://youtu.be/r-TLSBdHe1A) or the [github project](https://github.com/ccurtsinger/stabilizer) which discusses the these unpredicable performance fluctuations and the solution.

Comment: Haven't got to reading the assembly yet. Downloading stabilizer now. And @500 - Internal Server Error, changing my code from 4 cases to 2 with nested if's as you state got the time down to 5ms.

Comment: @B_half0rd: Actually my exact wording was rubbish, but good that you got the gist of it :)